# Complex INDEX MATCH returns #N/A

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

I've seen the solutions for getting the INDEX MATCH functions to return a zero instead of `#N/A` with ISNA or IFERROR. I've used these successfully in other projects. However, this one has me perplexed:

`=INDEX($B$4:$AQ$45,MATCH(C81,$A$4:$A$45,0),MATCH(D81,$B$3:$AQ$3,0))+INDEX($B$4:$AQ$45,MATCH(E81,$A$4:$A$45,0),MATCH(F81,$B$3:$AQ$3,0))`

How could I get this one to return a "0"?

I am basically looking up two values in a table, using a match of two separate criteria, then adding them together.  The `#N/A` wouldn't be a big deal, but my next function is:

```
=G2+(MAX(G46:G51))
```

Which basically adds all of the values, and it is returning the `#N/A` when it adds anything with `#N/A`, obviously.

Comment: I've added the [tag:excel] tag since this question appears to be about Excel. Feel free to correct it if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

`#N/A` errors will arise when C81 and/or E81 is/are not found in A4:A45 and/or D81 and/or F81 is/are not found in B3:AQ3. One pair is used to define the intercept for one of the values to be summed and the other pair for the intercept value of the other. Since an one or more of the four C81:F81 cells might not be found `#N/A` may be returned for either or both of the values to be summed, so [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) should be applied to each part of the equation that should return a value:

```
  =IFERROR(INDEX($B$4:$AQ$45,MATCH(C81,$A$4:$A$45,0),MATCH(D81,$B$3:$AQ$3,0)),0)+IFERROR(INDEX($B$4:$AQ$45,MATCH(E81,$A$4:$A$45,0),MATCH(F81,$B$3:$AQ$3,0)),0)
```

This is effectively: `=IFERROR(<first part>,0)+IFERROR(<second part>,0)`